# Failed sending mail through google api in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm trying to send an email through Google API.

I'm using [googleapis](https://www.npmjs.org/package/googleapis) for Google API access in node.js .

My issue is that when I try to send a simple mail with no attachments, I get the following error:

> 'raw' RFC822 payload message string or uploading message via /upload/* URL required

I didn't define in my request that there is an attachment and I don't see any error in the email addresses.

Please help.

My code:

```
    var google = require('googleapis');
    var gmailClass = google.gmail('v1');

    var email_lines = [];

    email_lines.push("From: \"Some Name Here\" <rootyadaim@gmail.com>");
    email_lines.push("To: hanochg@gmail.com");
    email_lines.push('Content-type: text/html;charset=iso-8859-1');
    email_lines.push('MIME-Version: 1.0');
    email_lines.push("Subject: New future subject here");
    email_lines.push("");
    email_lines.push("And the body text goes here");
    email_lines.push("<b>And the bold text goes here</b>");

    var email =email_lines.join("\r\n").trim();

    var base64EncodedEmail = new Buffer(email).toString('base64');

    gmailClass.users.messages.send({
        auth: OAuth2Client,
        userId: "me",
        message: 
        {
             raw: base64EncodedEmail
        }           
      },
    function(err, results){});
```

Comment: Did you try making `base64EncodedEmail` url-safe? Example: `base64EncodedEmail.replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_')`

Comment: @mscdex it did change parts in the string but I still got the same error

Comment: I have the same issue. The API seams to be responding the same no matter what I send.

Comment: I even tried sending back a raw message that I received as a response from the API itself. I got the same error message.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34546142/gmail-api-for-sending-mails-in-node-js/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Changes were made to version 1.0.3 of the google api. Try using the following syntax:

```
gmailClass.users.messages.send({
    auth: OAuth2Client,
    userId: "me",
    resource: 
    {
         raw: base64EncodedEmail
    }           
  }
```

Make sure that base64EncodedEmail is url safe. You can use the `base64EncodedEmail.replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_')` code posted by mscdex. This syntax worked for v. 1.0.11

Comment: Thank you for posting!  Was wondering why some of my code stopped working.  Where did you find out about this API update?  I ask because even Google's documentation still has it listed as `message`, not `resource` as of 10-21-14: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send