# Gmail API for sending mails in Node.js

Tags: node.js, gmail-api, google-api-nodejs-client

#### Disclaimer:

- I have followed Google's own [Node.js quickstart guide](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs) and successfully connect and use the  `gmail.users.labels.list()` functionality.
- I have checked for questions/answers here, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29515412/2256325) (that is not using the Node.js API I am asking about), or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25597617/2256325) (similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30613517/2256325)) which apparently is the same problem I have but the solution does not work.

#### My problem:

When using [Google's Node.js API](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client) I get a error trying to send a email. The error is:

```
{
    "code": 403,
    "errors": [{
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "insufficientPermissions",
        "message": "Insufficient Permission"
    }]
}
```

#### My setup:

```
fs.readFile(secretlocation, function processClientSecrets(err, content) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error loading client secret file: ' + err);
        return;
    }
    authorize(JSON.parse(content), sendMessage);
});

function sendMessage(auth) {
    var raw = makeBody('myrealmail@gmail.com', 'myrealmail@gmail.com', 'subject', 'message test');
    gmail.users.messages.send({
        auth: auth,
        userId: 'me',
        message: {
            raw: raw
        }
    }, function(err, response) {
        res.send(err || response)
    });
}
```

The function `processClientSecrets` is from the Google guide i mentioned above. It reads my `.json` file that has my `access_token` and `refresh_token`. The [`makeBody` function](https://gist.github.com/SergioCrisostomo/60de7a702ea839a64b32) is a to make a encoded body message.

In the config variabels I have also:

```
var SCOPES = [
    'https://mail.google.com/',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send'
];
```

#### Why it should work:

- the authorization process works for the `gmail.users.labels.list()` method.
- the message body I'm testing works if I test it at [Google's test page](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send).

---

#### My question:

Is my setup wrong? Have there been changes in the API? What am I missing?

Comment: Make sure you have the required scopes authorized: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send#auth

Comment: @AboulEinein I do, but still doesn't work, thanks for pointing. I had to have it also when testing in the [Google tool](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/gmail/v1/gmail.users.messages.send). Currently I have these _Auth scopes held_: `https://mail.google.com/, gmail.compose, gmail.modify, gmail.send`

Comment: Go to the [Oauth Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/), authorize with the Gmail Scopes, and take the `access token` and `refresh token` and put these in your `.json`-file. Do you still get an error?

Comment: @Tholle thanks for checking this out. Did that step you suggested and now the error is different: `{"code":400,"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"invalidArgument","message":"'raw' RFC822 payload message string or uploading message via /upload/* URL required"}]}`

Comment: @Sergio Hmm, that's annoying. Have you tried making the `raw`-string url safe (replace all `+` with `-` and all `/` with `_`)?

Comment: @Sergio Darn :( Then I don't know. Hopefully someone else can chime in.

Comment: @Tholle found my problem(s). Thanks for checking this!

Comment: @Sergio Great! No problem. :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Ok, so I found the problem(s).

**Problem #1**
While following the [Node.js quickstart guide](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs) the example in that tutorial has

```
var SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'];
```

And when I got the `.json` that looks like:

```
{
    "access_token": "xxx_a_long_secret_string_i_hided_xxx",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "refresh_token": "xxx_a_token_i_hided_xxx",
    "expiry_date": 1451721044161
}
```

those tokens where produced taking into account **only** the `auth/gmail.readonly` scope in the tutorial code.

So I deleted the first `.json`, added the scopes from my final scope array (i posted in the question) and ran the tutorial setup again, receiving a new token.

**Problem #2**

In the object passed to the API I was sending:

```
{
    auth: auth,
    userId: 'me',
    message: {
        raw: raw
    }
}
```

but that is wrong, `message` key should be called `resource`.

---

### Final setup:

This is what I added to the tutorial's code:

```
function makeBody(to, from, subject, message) {
    var str = ["Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n",
        "MIME-Version: 1.0\n",
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n",
        "to: ", to, "\n",
        "from: ", from, "\n",
        "subject: ", subject, "\n\n",
        message
    ].join('');

    var encodedMail = new Buffer(str).toString("base64").replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_');
        return encodedMail;
}

function sendMessage(auth) {
    var raw = makeBody('myrealemail@gmail.com', 'myrealemail@gmail.com', 'test subject', 'test message');
    gmail.users.messages.send({
        auth: auth,
        userId: 'me',
        resource: {
            raw: raw
        }
    }, function(err, response) {
        res.send(err || response)
    });
}
```

And call everything with:

```
fs.readFile(secretlocation, function processClientSecrets(err, content) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error loading client secret file: ' + err);
        return;
    }
    // Authorize a client with the loaded credentials, then call the
    // Gmail API.
    authorize(JSON.parse(content), sendMessage);
});
```

Comment: how to attach html payload?

Comment: @ArjunKava just set `Content-Type: text/html;` instead of `Content-Type: text/plain;`.

Comment: thank u @JyotmanSingh but i also need to send attachments within payload which are my local PC files , i have tried with mime content type but still not working.

Comment: Please, can you explain why you need to do some replacements over the base64 raw message. Thanks

Comment: I also would like to know why they replacements of the base64 content. Also, where did you find documentation about raw content is inside resource attribute.

Comment: this code has given me an this error : `'raw' RFC822 payload message string or uploading message via /upload/* URL required [400].`. This can be fixed by updating google-auth-api to the latest verstion. 

https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/979

Comment: You forgot `const gmail = google.gmail({version: 'v1', auth});` in `sendMessage()`. Also `res` in `sendMessage()` was not defined. After commenting it out, I got this error: `Error: Insufficient Permission`. Anyone else having this issue?

Comment: hello, How can I get an inbox email list? please advice. I already fetched list labels

Answer (score 8):

So for anyone looking at this trying to get a test email sent from their API but cant get this work heres what you gotta do:

Step 1:
Replace the

```
var SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'];
```

with this:

```
var SCOPES = [
    'https://mail.google.com/',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send'
];
```

Step 2:
At the end of googles sample code add this:

```
function makeBody(to, from, subject, message) {
    var str = ["Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n",
        "MIME-Version: 1.0\n",
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n",
        "to: ", to, "\n",
        "from: ", from, "\n",
        "subject: ", subject, "\n\n",
        message
    ].join('');

    var encodedMail = new Buffer(str).toString("base64").replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_');
        return encodedMail;
}

function sendMessage(auth) {
    var raw = makeBody('Receiverofyouremail@mail.com', 'whereyouaresendingstufffrom@gmail.com', 'This is your subject', 'I got this working finally!!!');
    const gmail = google.gmail({version: 'v1', auth});
    gmail.users.messages.send({
        auth: auth,
        userId: 'me',
        resource: {
            raw: raw
        }
    
    }, function(err, response) {
        return(err || response)
    });
}

fs.readFile('credentials.json', function processClientSecrets(err, content) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error loading client secret file: ' + err);
        return;
    }
    // Authorize a client with the loaded credentials, then call the
    // Gmail API.
    authorize(JSON.parse(content), sendMessage);
});
```

Step 3(Optional)

Delete this line:

```
authorize(JSON.parse(content), listLabels);
```

And these:

```
/**
 * Lists the labels in the user's account.
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
 function listLabels(auth) {
   const gmail = google.gmail({version: 'v1', auth});
   gmail.users.labels.list({
     userId: 'me',
   }, (err, res) => {
     if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
     const labels = res.data.labels;
     if (labels.length) {
       console.log('Labels:');
       labels.forEach((label) => {
         console.log(`- ${label.name}`);
       });
     } else {
       console.log('No labels found.');
     }
   });
 }
```

(So you don't get the random labels in your console)